# How "free" command is not working when creating shell script

Tags: linux, bash

I created bash script to find out cpu and other memory/cpu of different servers.

```
USER=name
DEST=\result.txt
FILE=\servers.txt

GetTotalCores="nproc --all"
GetMemoryDetails=" df -h | awk 'NR==2{print \$2}'"
GetMemoryDetails2=" df -h | awk 'NR==2{print \$2}'"
GetDetails="free -h"

for i in `cat $FILE`; 
do
    echo -n "."q
    D= "$(ssh name@$i.com $GetDetails)"
    A="$(ssh  name@$i.com $GetTotalCores)"
    B="$(ssh  name@$i.com $GetMemoryDetails)"
    C="$(ssh  name@$i.com $GetMemoryDetails2)"
    
    echo "${i} CPU: ${A} MEMORY: ${B}  ${C} RAM: ${D} >" >> ${DEST}

done
exit 0
```

When running the script everything is executed correctly exept "free command"

The result I am getting:

```
script.sh: line 27:               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       24669784     9181092      229024     1432604    15259668    13685616
Swap:       4063228      501760     3561468: No such file or directory
```

And nothing is printed into the destination file
I tried warapping it with different quotes but result is the same

Comment: Run `set -x` within the script (or start it with `bash -x yourscript`) to get a trace log showing how your script is actually being executed. If we see the xtrace log for the ssh command that fails, that'll be a significant help.

Comment: BTW, as a general rule, quote your expansions. `D="$(ssh "name@$i.example.com" "$GetDetails")"` has less that can go wrong than when you expand both `$i` and `$GetDetails` in unquoted contexts. (I don't expect any of those things to go wrong in your immediate circumstances, but the fewer variables the better).

Comment: Also, see [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). Better to use `while IFS= read -r i <&3; do ...; done 3<"$FILE"`

Comment: Also, all-caps variables are in the namespace meaningful to the shell itself and other POSIX-specified tools; you should use lowercase names for variables you define yourself -- see the relevant conventions at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that setting a regular shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable, so the same naming rules need to be followed for both.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.  The report includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Comment: AND you'll do well to read, review and take to heart the items on this page : https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info . Skip the Version information at the top and search for the sections  labeled "Before asking about Problematic code" and "How to turn a bad script into a good question" .Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Your script contains many oddities, but the main problem is that you are opening so many remote connections just to get a small nugget of information. It will be a lot more efficient to articulate the whole report remotely.

Also, redirect the output after `done` just once; this is a very minor efficiency improvement if the output file is small, but also very easy to make.

```
user="name"

while read -r server; do
    # echo -n "."q
    ssh "$name"@"$server.com" <<\____HERE |
        nproc --all
        df -h | awk 'NR==2{print $2}'
        # do you really need to run this command twice?
        free -h
____HERE
    awk -v i="$server" 'NR==1 { cpu=$0 }
        NR==2 { mem=$0 }
        NR==3 { printf "%s CPU: %s MEMORY: %s %s RAM: %s >\n",
            server, cpu, mem, mem, $0 }'
done<servers.txt >result.txt
```